# WinRT: 'where' not found when parsing XML

Tags: windows-runtime, linq-to-xml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am trying to parse some simple XML like this:

```
XElement thisLevel = from l in xmlElements.Descendants("Level")
                        where l.Element("LevelNum") == thisLevel
                        select l;
```

But I get an error on "levels" saying:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. 
>   'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive
>   for 'System.Linq'?

Strangely I can grab descendents:

```
var levels = xmlElements.Descendants("Level");
```

That works, but I can't seem to where on it.

Comment: Have you included a reference and a using directive for "Sytstem.Linq" as the error message asks?

Comment: Oops. I had mistakenly thought using System.Xml.Linq would include linq. A poor question on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ChrisF mentioned, these using statements are both required:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq; // this one was missing
```

I had thought System.Xml.Linq would cover all everything linq-related.

Thanks, ChrisF!